# Cannot read the value of a field from Json Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created a json Object and want to read the contents and put the values into dataTable.But I am not able to read the contents of Json object.

Below is my javascript function :

```
finalGrid : function(data){
            console.log("final Grid");
            var strJson = JSON.stringify(data);
            var dataJson = JSON.parse(strJson);
            console.log(dataJson);
            var table = $('#' + Dcn.tableId).dataTable();
            var tableObj = table.api();
            var rows = [];
            var field = Dcn.tableField;
            var count=0;
            $.each(dataJson, function(index, obj) {
                var row = [];
                row[field.dcnRefNo.index] = obj[field.dcnRefNo.name];
                row[field.name.index] = obj[field.name.name]";
                row[field.package.index] = obj[field.package.name];
                row[field.priority.index] = obj[field.priority.name];

                row.push("<button class='btn btn-labeled btn-success project-edit' " +
                        "onclick=\"Dcn.List.bindDcnStatusUpdate('"+obj["_id"]+"')\"> " +
                        "<span class='btn-label'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></span>View Dcn</button>");
            rows.push(row);
            count = count+1;
            console.log(count);
        });

        tableObj.rows.add(rows).draw();
        $('#' + Dcn.tableId).show();

    }
```

What to do ?

Comment: Offtopic: you have an invalid double quote on this line: `row[field.name.index] = obj[field.name.name]";` (second last character)

Comment: what's the purpose of doing `stringify` and then parsing it again ?

Comment: Paste Json object please.

Comment: @LinkinTED Thanks. That extra double quote might have come due to typing mistake.

Comment: @bpavlov  This is json string : {"package":"package-a","priority":"1","dcnRefNo":"DCN/Duraline/001","name":"abc"}. Json Object is  Object {package: "package-a", priority: "1", dcnRefNo: "DCN/Duraline/001", name: "abc"}

Comment: @Utkarsh I did it just to make sure I am getting the Json object in right format. Basically I am getting my Json string in the format {"package":"package-a","priority":"1","dcnRefNo":"DCN/Duraline/001","name":"abc"}.....whereas I need it in [{"package":"package-a","priority":"1","dcnRefNo":"DCN/Duraline/001","name":"abc"}] format.

Comment: Look into javascript console. Are you getting any js error ?

Comment: @Utkarsh No, I am not getting an js error.

Comment: What is the value of `dataJSON`?

Comment: @doveyg Object {package: "package-a", priority: "1", dcnRefNo: "DCN/Duraline/001", name: "abc"}

Answer (score 0):

If your json looks like this:

```
{"package": "package-a", "priority": "1", "dcnRefNo": "DCN/Duraline/001", "name": "abc"}
```

You could play with this code sample:

```
var data = [{"package": "package-a", "priority": "1", "dcnRefNo": "DCN/Duraline/001", "name": "abc"}];
function printJson(data){
            var strJson = JSON.stringify(data);
            var dataJson = JSON.parse(strJson);
            $.each(dataJson, function(index, obj) {
              console.log(obj.dcnRefNo);
              console.log(obj.name);
              console.log(obj.package);
              console.log(obj.priority);
        });
}
```

Comment: The value is not getting fetched.

Comment: Please see the comment above.